# Using a ransack filter to adjust join conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, ransack

Consider this model:

```
Merchant:
  id: int
  name: string

Purchase:
  id: int
  merchant_id: int
  created_at: datetime

Transactions:
  id: int
  purchase_id: int
  amount: decimal
```

Then, I've got an ActiveAdmin resource set up for Merchants, with on the index page a custom column that displays the sum of all Transaction amounts for all orders of that merchant.

What I want now is a date selector on the index page (probably in the filter section)  that allows me to select a date in the past after which I want the summed amounts to be calculated. (i.e. if I select October 1 2014, I only want the transactions summed up that belong to orders created from that date on).

So, the join conditions for Merchant to their Purchases should be configurable.

I know how to write a query for this in Rails and ActiveRecord, but I have no idea how to do this using Ransack for ActiveAdmin.

Comment: Is this something you're trying to do on the index page with a filter, with an action/link, or on a totally separate page?

Comment: I'm trying to do it on the index page, with a filter, I wish the column displaying the sum to change for all entries. *edited question*

Comment: Looked at my active admin app and we didn't use Ransack. We used filters and defined a scoped_collection to achieve this. Sorry.

Comment: @RyanCastillo Active Admin filters are based on Ransack, right? I'm happy to not use Ransack, but I thought I was stuck with it because I'm using active admin... I'll look into using a scoped collection.